# Image Gallery with Div Hover Overlay

Tags: javascript, css, hover, gallery, overlay

I would like to create an image Gallery for a client similar to the on Tiffany uses in the link bellow: 
[Tiffanys](http://www.tiffany.com/Shopping/CategoryBrowse.aspx?cid=622067&mcat=148204/)
 
 
However i am not very familiar with javascript and i am not sure if I even need to use it for 
 this or if there maybe another way, any suggestions would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

That scaling effect can be done easily with css3..here's an example

```
.image{
   -webkit-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out; 
   -moz-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out; 
   -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out; 
    transition: transform .3s ease-out; /*this is for the transition to go smoother*/
}


 .image:hover
{
   -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
   -o-transform: scale(1.3);
   transform: scale(1.3);/*scaling effect*/
}
```